# LinkButton doesn't raise postback on IIS7 and IE7

Tags: asp.net

Why with LinkButton doesn't work postback with IE7 and work with FW3.+ when site work on IIS7?

Comment: I don't think IIS7 has anything to do with it. Can you post your ASP.NET code and also the rendered HTML?

Comment: ASP.NET code:
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowPaymentHistory" runat="server" CssClass="RedLink" Text="Show payment history" ></asp:LinkButton>

and rendered html:
<a id="RightMenu1_btnShowPaymentHistory" class="RedLink" href="javascript:__doPostBack('RightMenu1$btnShowPaymentHistory','')">Show payment history</a>

Comment: Maybe it works when you add CausesValidation="false" to the LinkButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you testing on your your productive server(f.e. Windows Server 2008) with high security settings in IE? Use a client with normal security settings and javascript enabled as mentioned before.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you. The solution was in adding site to trusted in IE settings

Answer (score 0):

Is there some kind of JavaScript error on the page that is preventing Javascript from running in IE7 and hence no postback?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got javascript enabled? Link buttons use the __doPostback Javascript method. For a non-javascript reliant postback, use regular asp:Button controls.